# Delete objects from DB within before_flush event (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In `before_flush` event I have to do the following actions:

1. Issue some select queries for check that I can do some actions
2. **Delete** some objects from collection B
3. Check that **in collection B there are not objects** with some criteria (2)
4. Add to collection B a list of objects

The problem is that when at point 3 I do select query it still return the objects which I marked as deleted at point 2. But I want an empty list from it. :)

All this actions I have to do inside one transaction. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have solve your problem? Can share? Thanks.